# Subversive for Eclipse not visible

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins

I installed the subversive plugin for Eclipse to use SVN. The installation was OK, no problems. I restarted Eclipse, the plugin is visible by "Installed software". But if I look at Team -> share or Window -> preferences team SVN is not visible. Someone an idea?

Comment: Not to imply that you're making a wrong choice, but you might also consider using Subclipse: http://subclipse.tigris.org/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try switching to the svn repository perspective? Can you see it (top right corner, drop down menu, "other")?